# Is an embedded error exported?

Tags: go, embedding

According to the [Go language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types), I can embed a type in a struct.

There is a weird case with the `error` interface. It is not uppercased, so I assume it is not exported as a type. But it is defined by the language. So if I have a struct like this:

```
package foo

type Err struct {
    error
}
```

is the embedded `error` exported? Does `Err` satisfy the `error` interface?

Can I access it from another package, i.e. is the following ok?

```
package main

import "errors"
import "fmt"
import "foo"

func main() {
    e := foo.Err{}
    e.error = errors.New("Hello world!") // is this okay?
    fmt.Println(e.Error())
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you embed an `error` interface into a struct, basically, you add a field named `error` with type `error` to it.

Because it's embedded your struct now also implements all of it's methods. That means your struct satisfies the `error` interface and you can call `Error()` on it or just pass it to `Println` as it is and it will type assert it into `error` and call `Error()` for you https://play.golang.org/p/0VxUUX2l-z

Obviously, because field is named `error` it's not exported. But the struct still satisfies the `error` interface because it has `Error()` method.

Interesting consequence of this is that if you don't initialize the field `Println` will panic because it will try to call `Error()` on nil  https://play.golang.org/p/XctFgKZI-K

Answer (score 0):

```golang
e := foo.Err{}
e.error = errors.New("Hello world!") // error
```

This will cause an error since `e.error` is not accessible from outside package.
If you need to set this field, you may declare a constructor:

```golang
func NewError(err error) *Error {
    return &Error{error: err}
}
```

But if you really need to export this field, this is still possible: you may declare  a type alias:

```golang
type Error struct {
    Err
}
type Err = error
```

Then you may access `e.Err` field from outside package.

Comment: inspired by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389339/15422494