# Embed two structs with the same name in a struct

Tags: inheritance, go, struct, interface

How do you embed two types of the same name in a struct? For instance:

```
type datastore {
    *sql.Store
    *file.Store
}
```

Results in `duplicate field Store`. I know this makes sense, since you wouldn't be able to refer to the embedded field `ds.Store` but how do you accomplish this anyway?

To clarify, I want to implement an interface with `datastore`. For that both structs are needed as their methods complement each other to create the interface. What alterantives do I have?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on how the methods of those embedded strutcts complement each other exactly?

Comment: Please check out my answer, I believe it is the more elegant way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a [type alias](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#language), example:

```
type SqlStore = sql.Store // this is a type alias

type datastore struct {
    *SqlStore
    *file.Store
}
```

A type alias doesn’t create a new distinct type different from the type it’s created from. It just introduces an alias name `sqlStore`, an alternate spelling, for the type denoted by `sql.Store`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to first wrap your `whatever.Store` into distinct-named types:

```
import (
    "os"
    "whatever/sql"
)

type SqlStore struct {
    *sql.Store
}

type FileStore struct {
     *os.File
}

type DataStore struct {
     SqlStore
     FileStore
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/6FpnYqXbHR).

Note that Go 1.9 might gain support for type aliases: see [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16339) and [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18130).  I'm not sure that would help in your case but might be interesting to learn about.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed refer to a field even if present in two different substructures included as anonymous fields:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    x int32
}

type B struct {
    x int32
}

type C struct {
    A
    B
}

func main() {
    c := C{A{1}, B{2}}
    //fmt.Println(c.x) // Error, ambiguous
    fmt.Println(c.A.x) // Ok, 1
    fmt.Println(c.B.x) // Ok, 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply "name" the two "Stores" differently in your struct. When you do not name an embedded struct field in a struct, it defaults to the name of the Embedded Struct, so, here, you have two fields named "Store", but you can easily make the name explicit. so go with this:

```
package main

import (
    "file"
    "fmt"
    "sql"
)

type Datastore struct {
    sqlStore  *sql.Store
    fileStore *file.Store
}

func main() {
    ds := Datastore{&sql.Store{SqlStoreName: "MySQLStore"}, &file.Store{FileStoreName: "MyFileStore"}}

    fmt.Println(ds.sqlStore.SqlStoreName, ds.fileStore.FileStoreName)
}
```

This works fine for me.