# Struct creation: Is there a difference between declaration and expression?

Tags: go

In my testing, these 2 seem to behave the same way:

```golang
// declaration
type Decl struct { }

// expression
type Expr = struct { }
```

I can't seem to find anything in [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec) that pertains to this specifically.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Type declarations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations), the syntax without an equal sign (`type A B`) defines *a distinct type*, while the other one (`type A = B`) defines *an alias*.

See for example:

```
type A struct{}

type B = struct{}

func (a A) String() string {
    return "A"
}

// Does not compile: invalid receiver type struct{}
// func (b B) String() string {
//     return "B"
// }
```

An alias is equivalent to its source type, except for a different name, which [affects embedding in structs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389339/5958455).